# TypeScript and AngularJS - Module is undefined?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have been writing a rather large AngularJS app of directives in TypeScript according to the following article: http://kwilson.me.uk/blog/writing-cleaner-angularjs-with-typescript-and-controlleras/.

I have organized my Controllers and Directives into subfolers of my appm `Controllers`, and `Directives`.

My `main.ts` looks like so:

```
module Test {
    angular.module("myModule", ["myDep"])
           .controller(Test.Controllers)
           .directive(Test.Directives);
    }
}
```

my `_all.ts` looks like so

```
/// <reference path='Controllers/x.ts' />
/// <reference path='Directives/x.ts' />
/// <reference path='Controllers/y.ts' />
/// <reference path='Directives/y.ts' />
/// <reference path='Test/main.ts' />
```

Everything has been working great, until I attempted to add a service.

I took some duplicated functions between the controllers `x` and `y` and put them in a service, under the folder `Services`

```
module Test.Services {
    export class TestService {

        test(): string {
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

added it to my `_all.ts`

```
/// <reference path='Controllers/x.ts' />
/// <reference path='Directives/x.ts' />
/// <reference path='Controllers/y.ts' />
/// <reference path='Directives/y.ts' />
/// <reference path='Services/test.ts' />
/// <reference path='Test/main.ts' />
```

and attempted to add it to my app:

```
module Test {
    angular.module("myModule", ["myDep"])
           .controller(Test.Controllers)
           .directive(Test.Directives)
           .service("testService", Test.Services.TestService);
    }
}
```

I can get everything to compile, and IntelliSense seems to accept it, but when I render my page, I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'TestService' of undefined
```

It doesn't seem to see my Test.Services module, and I can't figure out why. It is clearly compiling, I can see the Services in the transpiled JavaScript.

If I attempt to do a

```
console.log(Test.Services);
```

in `main.ts`, I get `undefined`, but not for `Controllers` or `Directives`

If I move my service into the same module `Test` that `angular.module` gets called in, it works - but only if it is in the same lexical scope as the `angular.module` call. If I keep it in the same separate file, but in the `Test` module, it doesn't work.

I am very confused here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am very confused here

This is the hazard of using `out`. See lots of reasons why you shouldn't : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

## Temp fix:

Reorder the files in `_all.ts` so that the variables are declared in the order they are used

## Long term fix:

Use `commonjs` everywhere and for the frontend have something like `webpack` running.

Comment: Sigh, this is it. I actually did try reordering my `_all.ts` beforehand without any success.However, when I changed the order that VS was passing TypeScript files to the compiler, everything worked.

I'll pass this information along to my team.